# Составить слово из символов

Tags: c++, сравнение, словари

Вводится последовательность символов(латинский алфавит). Из них требуется составить как можно больше слов. Подскажите, как это реализовать. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А можно пример? И что подразумевается под словом, слово английского языка или любая последовательность букв?

Comment: Вроде "t", "a", "c" => "cat", "at"?

Answer (score 1):

Для каждого введенного сивола:

1. пробегать по словарю и выбирать слова, которые начинаются на эту
   букву и по длине соответствуют кол-ву введенных символов.
2. пробегать по выборке слов и проверять каждую букву в слове, начиная
       со второй, на соответсвие одной из списка введенных символов
3. Если проверка дошла до конца слова то вывести его